# Weird solid color layer thumbnail in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This has happened a couple times; the normal thumbnail looks like this :
[image]

but for some reason i've been getting this one lately:

[image]

It doesn't seem to have an effect on my projects but i'm just curious about the reason why it changed. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a setting which affects all layers, not just solid color layers.

If you click on the *Layers* panels' "sandwich" menu in the top right corner, and select *Panel Options...*, you can choose between different thumbnail sizes:

[image: Layers Panel Options]